# FB.login Redirect in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, pyramid

The following function is bound to a button onclick handler.  The way it is supposed to work is that once a user authenticates via Facebook they redirect to a page (on the same site) which authenticates them using the Facebook cookie.  The /fb/login endpoint, once authentication succeeds, forwards them on the the page they just logged in at.

```
function ButtonFBLogin(){
    FB.login(function(response){
        if(response.authResponse){
            window.location.href = '/fb/login';
        }
    }
});
```

This redirect works in Chrome and Firefox.  In IE it makes a GET request to the /fb/login, and redirects to the page that the user came from, but the user is not authenticated.

Thing I've tried:

- Wrap the redirect in a setTimeout to put it on the event queue, but I still have the same problem.
- document.location.href instead of window.location.href
- Cache busting by appending ?tmp= to the URL

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Pyramid.  I have filed an issue report with them:
[Issue Thread](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/1243)

Basically, Pyramid allows you to specify a max_age for an authentication ticket.  This parameter sets the max-age parameter of the cookie, but not the expires parameter.  Firefox and Chrome both correctly handle this max-age field.  Internet Explorer does not.

It uses the max-age seconds integer as the value for the expires field.  Internet Explorer expects the expires field to be set in RFC 1123 format (Wdy, DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT).  It cannot understand an integer  in the expires field.  Instead of keeping the cookie around it throws it out.  [See Wikipedia for a discussion of max-age and expires.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age)

Hope this prevents someone else from banging their head on the nearest desk!